# urxvt map esc key to key sequence

Tags: vim, mutt, urxvt

This question is a spin-off of [Rebinding "clear prompt" in mutt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47773/rebinding-clear-prompt-in-mutt)

I use vim keybindings a lot and like using <kbd>esc</kbd> to abort commands. I've now moved to mutt but it is not possible to bind <kbd>esc</kbd> to 'abort' in Mutt (see above).  Instead, I would like to map <kbd>esc</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd>. My hope is to get the <kbd>esc</kbd> key to send both key sequences. That way <kbd>esc</kbd> is a kind of universal abort key for vim and mutt.

I've mapped <kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd> to 'no operation' in .vimrc with  `nmap <C-g> <nop>` so there's no conflict in Vim.

Preferably I would like this mapping to be set in .Xdefaults or .Xresources so that the strange <kbd>esc</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd> mapping only applies to urxvt (my terminal em) and programs run inside it.  By making this apply more globally in Xinput or Xmodmap I will have to stay on the lookout for what this mapping does to other (possibly non-cli) programs.  That said, any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `keysym` resource. This requires that rxvt has been compiled with the `--enable-frills` option. Put this line in your `~/.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.keysym.Escape: \033\007
```

Run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` to reload the resource files. The settings only apply to programs started after running `xrdb -merge`.

If you want, you can have different settings depending on a parameter passed to rxvt. Choose a name like `urxvt-mutt`; it must begin with a lowercase letter and should begin with `urxvt` so that it doesn't conflict with names used by other applications. Add this line to `~/.Xresources`:

```
urxvt-mutt.keysym.Escape: \033\007
```

Then when you run `urxvt -name urxvt-mutt` you'll get this binding (overriding any binding set with `URxvt.keysym.Escape`), but when you run `urxvt` with no `-name` option you'll only get the `URxvt` bindings.

Comment: I was aware of `keysym` but how did you find the code `\033\007` ?

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I tried for hours to do this before asking on se.  I wish I had more rep to give you as a reward.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If i understood correctly, terminals use octal values and we are talking about escape sequences. Escape has the decimal value of `27`, which in octal is `033`. Therefore <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>, which has the decimal value `7`, has the octal value `007` (BEL). Hence `\033\007`. And if I'm correct, you need to place a `command:` before that sequence.

Comment: @WGRM Your understanding of the syntax is correct, but not your understanding of whose syntax it is. The `Some.thing: stuff` syntax and backslash-octal in strings are [X resources](http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/XWindow-User-HOWTO-8.html). The dotted names before the colon (`Some.thing`) are a property of the application.