# mutt: bind CTRL+c to abort (CTRL+g)

Tags: mutt

In mutt, when I use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I want it to behave as if I had pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. I understand that simple `bind`, such as the following,  will not work:

```
bind    index   \Cc             <abort>
```

but there must be some way how to do it (perhaps some macro?).

My question is similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47773/rebinding-clear-prompt-in-mutt) question, but the accepted answer is not acceptable for me. I need some way how to solve this problem in mutt (and not in the terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only do you have the problems mentioned in the linked question, but the kernel also intercepts the control c and directs it as a signal. So you would need to modify the signal handler, or use stty to change your break character.

Comment: I did not mean to intercept CTRL-c. I thought, perhaps I could configure mutt what to do when it receives CTRL-c (I want it to behave as if it had received CTRL-g)